# Set Default Page

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I am running IIS 7.5 and in my VS2015 project I have set the start page, I also have set the start page using my webconfig file like so:

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
      <add value="~/Page1.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

But anytime I try to browse my site I get a

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start --> Run --> inetmgr
Click Your Site
Click Default Document
Add whatevs the name of your start-up page should be

As far as your comment above, did you update the "Web" file in the root of the drive or the "web" file in the same location as your .aspx pages?

Comment: that was my issue, I was updating the wrong "web" file.